# Conditional insertion trigger

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, sql-server-2000

Whenever a row is inserted into Course_Enrollment and the enrollment_date value is not explicitly given in the insertion statement (i.e., it is missing), 
then the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP value is used for the Enrollment_date column of the inserted row.

Is this possible with TSQL 2000? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a default value for the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP column of `getdate()`.